# how to render properly all drop down list with jquery function in asp.net 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, msdropdown

i just made one user control with Drop Down list. here i'm using [msdropdownlist](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) for binding images with it. now i just want to when page load then all Drop Down list renders with msdropdownlist one of jquery function. I know this one can made with jquery + html - select selector function. now here my problem is when user selects any drop down list then selected index changed event fires after that it's doesn,t rendered with msdropdownlist jquery function.

here i include my jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    try {
        $("#<%=DDL_Column_List.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_Categorynames.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_Usernames.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_StatusList.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_GroupList.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_UserList1.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_StatusList1.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
        $("#<%=DDL_GroupList1.ClientID %>").msDropDown();
} catch (e) {
alert(e.message);
}
});
</script>
```

here i just want to make one common function for all drop down list found per page. then it's getting upper function. And it renders properly if user has been getting change item selection.

please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologise if I misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish, but do you mean this?

```
$('select').msDropDown();
```

Edit:
Put both scripts in your page then pick one that fires after postback and replace console.log with code above. You can see log messages fired by opening your page in Google Chrome then going to console (Ctrl+Shift+I)

```
$(window).load(function () {
   console.log("window loaded");
});
$(function () {
  console.log('document ready');
});
```

Comment: this works fine at first page load. but when i select item from this list after post back drop down not rendered with msDropDown jquery function.

Comment: are u saying putting both script. and see which fires first after post back. here document.ready output shows first order to show then i have to out this script in second block.

Comment: this should do it: $(function () {
  $('select').msDropDown();
});

Comment: same issue after post back it's getting normal.

Comment: try this  $(function () { console.log($('select').length); }); and check if number differs before and after postback

Comment: Try to remove (not sure how to do this) msDropDown and add it again on every call.

Comment: Here's article that tries to remove styling http://forum.jquery.com/topic/msdropdown-remove-msdropdown-styling

Comment: how can i write this as u specified.

Comment: plase post html of dropdown with ms style applied.

Comment: ok. it's getting normal style with drop down list. how i recall as u suggested.